# Swift 3 operator precedence order

Tags: swift, operators

In the [Swift Standard Library Operators API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/swift_standard_library_operators) there is a table showing "default" operators including their associativity and precedence group.

> The tables below list the operators declared in the standard library, including their associativity and precedence group. Table 1 lists the prefix operators and Table 2 lists the infix operators. For more information about operation declarations, see Operator Declaration in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1).

I can't find any reference mentioning whether the table represents operators ordered by precedence or not.

**Does anyone know if the above mentioned table is ordered by precedence?**

Is it documented anywhere, just to be sure?

That would result in such ordered precedence (from higher to lower):
`Bitwise shift`
`Multiplication`
`Addition`
`Range formation`
`Casting`
`Nil coalescing`
`Comparison`
`Logical conjunction`
`Ternary`
`Assignment`

Thanks